# Save the temporary files produced during the compilation

Tags: compiling, auxiliary-files

I know that when we compile a .tex file, pdflatex or the compiling program generates temporary files. I would like to know how I can make these files be saved in the source folder of the compiled .tex file. I'm using MikTeX and TexWorks. How can I achieve this?

Comment: they are saved by default, you must be running some script to delete them. `\ref` or `\tableofcontents` will not work if they are deleted

Comment: check in the texworks settings if there is a --clean option set somewhere.

Comment: The @UlrikeFischer work perfectly. You need to open the editing window of a compiling tool, like "pdfLaTex + MakeIndex + BibTeX" and then erase the "--clean" action. Thanks